# Select Max() of SUM() for a Group

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum, max

```
SELECT tname , pname , SUM(Goals)
FROM team as t , player as p , matches as m 
WHERE t.TID=p.TID AND p.PNB=m.PNB
Group BY pname , tname
ORDER BY `SUM(Goals)`  DESC
```

I need to Select only the player who have more goals in each team.Example it will shown only Luis Suarez from F.C Barcelona and Munir fROM SEVILLA ....

[image: I need to Select only the player who have more goals in each team.Example it will shown only Luis Suarez from F.C Barcelona and Munir fROM SEVILLA ....]

Comment: What about "Karim Benzema" ? Why is he not in the results ?

Comment: Yes i mean all the list karim, morata, and reus

Comment: What if there are two same player numbers in your database in table player? Player number can not be the column you will use to join with table matches to check goals ?

Comment: PNB is unique ,can't be the same

Comment: which version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  Commas were superseded over **20** years ago.

Then, you want window functions:

```
SELECT tp.*
FROM (SELECT t.tname, p.pname, SUM(m.Goals) as goals,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.tname ORDER BY SUM(m.Goals) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM matches m JOIN
           team t
           ON t.TID = p.TID JOIN
           player p  
           ON p.PNB = m.PNB
      GROUP BY p.pname, t.tname
     ) tp
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY goals DESC;
```

This returns all players with the highest values.  If you want just one row, use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()`.

Comment: can you explain to me what seqnum = 1 mean? and thanks

Comment: @feyiz beik: `RANK` ranks the rows, giving the best players per team #1. This rank gets the alias name `seqnum`. Hence `WHERE seqnum = 1` means "show only the best".

Comment: @feyizbeik This works just fine. Maybe the join's are little bit wrong but this is the correct way to do it. Join like this maybe: `FROM team t 
join player p  on t.TID=p.TID 
join matches m on p.PNB=m.PNB`

Comment: tp is an alias for the subquery. Every subquery in MySQL has to have an alias. Also, do not forget you can also vote up for the answer if I am not wrong :) Not just accept it ...

Comment: if one team has player goals same, how can i limit to show only one player .

Comment: like Dortmund has reus and alcacer how can i choose only one